# json call not trggering success or error with status code 200

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-ajax

```
 $.ajax(
{  
 type: 'GET',
 url: 'url&callback=?',
 contentType: "application/x-javascript",   crossDomain: true,  data: "{}",
 dataType: 'jsonp',
 success: function(json) {
 console.log(json);

},
error: function(e) {
   console.log(e.message);
}
});
```

It gives success message on using dataType script though url is returning json response .        Response is:-

[{
    "Sr.No": 1,
    "ClientVisitName": null,
    "VisitorID": "001",
    "FromDate": "3/1/2014",
    "ToDate": "3/18/2014",
    "BusinessUnit": "Marketing",
    "Location": "Chennai",
    "SpocID": null,
    "Crtuser": null,
    "Crtdate": null,
    "ModUser": null,
    "ModDate": null
}, {
    "Sr.No": 2,
    "ClientVisitName": null,
    "VisitorID": "002",
    "FromDate": "3/3/2014",
    "ToDate": "3/27/2014",
    "BusinessUnit": "Mobility",
    "Location": "Pune",
    "SpocID": null,
    "Crtuser": null,
    "Crtdate": null,
    "ModUser": null,
    "ModDate": null
}]

am using .net webservice with type "application/x-javascript"